# Why values dont shows in custom post column?

Tags: post-meta, columns

I have some trouble.

```
/* Catalog */
function my_post_type_catalog() {
    register_post_type( 'catalog',
                array( 
                'label' => __('Catalog'), 
                'public' => true, 
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'rewrite' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'supports' => array(
                        'title',
                        'editor',
                        'thumbnail',
                        'excerpt')
                    ) 
                );
    register_taxonomy('catalog_cat', 'catalog', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Catalog category', 'singular_name' => 'catalog_category'));
}

add_action('init', 'my_post_type_catalog');


add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("catalogdetails_meta", "Price:", "catalog_meta",  "catalog", "normal", "low");
}

function catalog_meta() {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $price = $custom["price"][0];
  ?>  

    <div id='peoplemanager_form_container'>

        <div id='shortanswers'>
            <p><input name="price" size="35" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
  global $post;

  update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $_POST["price"]);
}


// Register the column
function price_column_register( $columns ) {
    $columns['price'] = __( 'Price' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-catalog_columns', 'price_column_register' );


// Display the column content
function price_column_display( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'price' != $column_name )
        return;

    $price = get_post_meta($post_id, 'price', true);
    if ( !$price )
        $price = '<em>' . __( 'undefined' ) . '</em>';

    echo $price;
}
add_action( 'manage_catalog_post_custom_column', 'price_column_display', 10, 2 );


// Register the column as sortable
function price_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['price'] = 'price';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-catalog_sortable_columns', 'price_column_register_sortable' );


function price_column_orderby( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'price' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'price',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        ) );
    }

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'price_column_orderby' );
```

The price values not shows. What do I wrong ?
...
Thanks for **@Brady**

need replace this code:

```
// Display the column content
function price_column_display( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'price' != $column_name )
        return;

    $price = get_post_meta($post_id, 'price', true);
    if ( !$price )
        $price = '<em>' . __( 'undefined' ) . '</em>';

    echo $price;
}
add_action( 'manage_catalog_post_custom_column', 'price_column_display', 10, 2 );
```

to:

```
// Display the column content
add_action('manage_catalog_posts_custom_column', 'sc_stores_manage_columns', 10, 2);
function sc_stores_manage_columns($column_name, $id) {
    $custom = get_post_custom($id);
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'price':
            if ($custom["price"][0]==""){echo "none";}
            echo $custom["price"][0];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_action( 'manage_post_custom_column', 'price_column_display', 10, 2 );`

This line is wrong. I think it should be:

`add_action( 'manage_catalog_post_custom_column', 'price_column_display', 10, 2 );`

The hook format is as follows:

`manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column`

**EDIT:**

try your custom column code like the following code. I know in this format it works:

```
add_action('manage_stores_posts_custom_column', 'sc_stores_manage_columns', 10, 2);
function sc_stores_manage_columns($column_name, $id) {
    $custom = get_post_custom($id);
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'town':
            echo $custom["sc_stores_town"][0];
        break;

        case 'road':
            echo $custom["sc_stores_road"][0];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: please update your question to include the updated code. And nots not working? please me a bit more specific

Comment: sorting is works. but values not shows in column.
http://dropmocks.com/mWtcb

Comment: @Bobrov Alexey see edit.